# Product sigma-algebra: approximating elements arbitrary good using the generating sets

Tags: measure-theory

I am struggling to find a reference for the following statement, which I still believe to be true.

"Let  $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1, \mu_1), (\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2, \mu_2)$ be finite measure spaces. Furthermore, let $(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2, \mu_1\otimes\mu_2)$ the usual product measure space. Then, for every $A\in \mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2$ there are sequences $(B_1^i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{A}_1, (B_2^i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{A}_2$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_1^i\times B_2^i\subset A$ and $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_1^i\times B_2^i)\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$."

So, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra that is the classical picture that you can approach measurable sets by unions of rectangluar sets.
I would also be fine with a statement that approximates $A$ with bigger sets, so $A\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n_j} B_1^{i,j}\times B_2^{i,j}$ for any $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and for $j\to\infty$ I have that $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)((\cup_{i=1}^{n_j} B_1^{i,j}\times B_2^{i,j})\backslash A)$.

Thank you very much for every answer in advance.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot one property, which I added. Also, if it is easier I would also be happy with an approximation with "bigger" sets.

Comment: This statement is trivial: Take $B_1^i=\Omega_1$ and $B_2^i=\Omega_2$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I forgot the restriction, that the union should be a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\Om\Omega\newcommand\A{\mathcal A}\newcommand\I{\mathbb I}$Your original statement is trivial: Take $B_1^i=\Omega_1$ and $B_2^i=\Omega_2$ for all $i$.

If you additionally require that $B_1^i\times B_2^i\subseteq A$ for all $i$, then the statement will become false in general. For instance, for $j=1,2$ let $(\Om_j,\A_j,\mu_j)$ be the standard Lebesgue measure space over $[0,1]$. Let $A=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\colon x-y\in\I\}$, where $\I$ is the set of all irrational real numbers. Then (by, say, the Tonelli theorem), $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A)=1$. However, if $B_1\times B_2 \subseteq A$, then $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(B_1\times B_2)=0$, because otherwise the set $B_1-B_2=\{x-y\colon x\in B_1,y\in B_2\}$ would contain a nonzero-length interval and therefore would contain a rational point as an element -- cf. e.g [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Iosif-Pinelis/publication/280132389_150600537v2/data/55abc6d608aea3d0868593f2/150600537v2.pdf?origin=ResearchDetailAlternativeSimilarResearch&_rtd=eyJjb250ZW50SW50ZW50Ijoic2ltaWxhciJ9). So, for any $B_j^i\in\A_j$ such that $B_1^i\times B_2^i\subseteq A$ for all $i$, we will have $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n(B_1\times B_2))=1\not\to0$.

Similarly, in general you cannot approximate a set $A\in\A_1\otimes\A_2$ by bigger sets (containing $A$) belonging to the algebra of all finite unions of the products of sets in $\A_1$ and $\A_2$ -- just consider the complement of the set $A$ in the example above. (Do not confuse the product $\sigma$-algebra $\A_1\otimes\A_2$, generated by the mentioned algebra, with the product $\A_1\times\A_2$ of the $\sigma$-algebras $\A_1$ and $\A_2$.)

---

What is possible is for each natural $n$ to find a set $B_n$ belonging to the mentioned algebra of all finite unions of of the products of sets in $\A_1$ and $\A_2$ such that $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A+B_n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, where $+$ denotes the symmetric difference -- see e.g. Theorem 1.1 [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11117-017-0507-8) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01142).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is very interesting. But do you think it is possible to find an approximation with union that contain A? In your example one could choose $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$?

Comment: @LoyoL : No, you cannot do it with containing sets either. I have also added what you can do.